# GZipStream out of memory exception on decompression

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, gzip, gzipstream

I have a massive large dataset that contains almost 700 columns and I,m using GZipStream for compression and decompression. Compression works fine and size of the dataset after compression is almost 40mb, but I get "**system out of memory**" exception during decompression. I,m using below code for compression and decompression:

**Compression:**

```
public static Byte[] CompressDataSet(DataSet dataset)
{
    Byte[] data;
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress);
    dataset.WriteXml(zip, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    zip.Close();
    data = mem.ToArray();
    mem.Close();
    return data;
```

}

**Decompression:**

```
public static DataSet DecompressDataSet(Byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    dataset.ReadXml(zip, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    zip.Close();
    mem.Close();
    return dataset;

}
```

Please recommend any other compression library if GZipStream is not optimal/suitable for massive large datasets. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is stemming from the way you're compressing the data in the first place, have a look at the code below and let me know if you have any questions.

```
public static Byte[] CompressDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
{
    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(resultStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        dataSet.WriteXml(inputStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        inputStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);

        gzipStream.Close();

        return resultStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static DataSet DecompressDataSet(Byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (DataSet dataset = new DataSet())
    {
        dataset.ReadXml(gzipStream, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

Comment: the compression approcah you prescribed above uses CPU and memory highly and keep on running..we have to stop it forcefully as it keeps on running using huge memory and CPU

Comment: I'm using the same approach your question is based off, I tested with data in excess of 100mb and it worked fine. Your implementation doesn't actually compress anything which is why you are having issues in the first place